# most favorable path in a graph (but not the shortest)

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am struggling to find an algorithm that can answer the following question  regarding the given graph example [image]. Let's say that nodes A,B,C ....H represents countries. The aim of the algorithm : carrying the maximal amount of a certain item  from A to G while respecting the law on how many items you are allowed to carry from one country to another. The number of allowed items are given as the weight of the directed edges. It would also be great, but not mandatory, that the algorithm can sort the different possible paths .  On that graph, the result is :
1 : A > H > G with 145 items
2 : A > C > G with 140 items
3 : A > B > F > G; A > B > D > G; A > C > B > F > G; A > C > B > D > G all leading to 50 items.

The algorithm should be able not to get stuck in the (C>B>D) loop or by the A>B>E dead end.

At the beginning, I was thinking about the Dijkstra shortest path algorithm using the inverse of the weight as weight. But I realized that this not what I want since my problem is more a matter of limiting steps. From reading a little about Ant Colony Optimization, I am not sure it can either answer  my problem. It would be very kind if someone can help me :)

Comment: They keyword is "maximum flow", not "shortest path" ;)

Comment: Look at this answer on the computer science stackexchange: [Finding the maximum bandwidth along a single path in a network](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1639)

Comment: Thank you very much @stef. Studying your answers help me realizing that my real life problem is a bit more complicated than the graph I gave as an example. Nevertheless, I have now new trails to follow. I'll edit my post in case I do not find a solution by myself .